# Looping through the boundary of a rectangle between two points on the rectangle?

Tags: c#, loops, line, intersection

Whew, that was a big one.
[image: Diagram]
Right, so I have two points, on the boundary of the rectangle and also on the two lines, which are cast from the origin. The arrangement of P1/P2 is arbitrary, for the sake of simplicity.

My question is, **how can I loop through the green area (The smallest area, basically) of the rectangle?**

The implementation: I want to create a field-of-vision effect in a game that I am creating. The origin is the player, who can be anywhere on the current viewport (The rectangle). The lines' directions are offset from the direction that the player is facing. I intend to trace all positions on the green area from the origin, checking for obstructions.

**I would prefer a code example answer, any language, but preferably C#**

Comment: Your question can't be answered. What do you mean by "loop through"? What is there to loop in a rectangle?

Comment: Loop through each integer coordinate on the highlighted area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you want is something like this:

All coordinates C with the following criteria are on the green line that is part of the rectangle R:

```
(P1.y == P2.y)
?
(
    C.x >= P1.x && C.x <= P2.x
)
:
(
  (C.x >= P2.x && C.x <= R.right && C.y == P2.y) || 
  (C.x >= P1.x && C.x <= R.right && C.y == P1.y) || 
  (C.x == R.x && C.y <= P1.y && C.y >= P2.y)
)
```

This assumes that P1 will be below P2 in case they are not on the same line and that P1 will be before P2 if they are on the same line.

Comment: So, say I loop around all points on the boundary of said rectangle, and checked each point with this, would it return true for every point in the green area?

Comment: There is no green area in your image. This will only return true for points on the green **line** as illustrated in your question...

Comment: Sorry, I misworded my question. But yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Also; I imagine the 'X.y' is actually 'C.y'?

Comment: Your test does not apply to cases where p1/p2 are on the same line. When I tested, the two points were on the top line of the rectangle, but the returned valid coordinates started at p1, and ended at the right-top edge of the rectangle.

Comment: I have not tested other edges yet. I will get back to you, and many thanks :D

Comment: What are those cases? I think you should be able to fix them on your own, it isn't that hard...

Comment: p1 on left, p2 on top.
both on left & right.
both on bottom.
p1 on bottom, p2 on left.
p2 on bottom, p1 on right.
p1 on top, p2 on right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out which objects are in the "green area"...

Assuming you know the size of the rectangle you can calculate the vertices of the polygon you're interested in (origin, P1, P2 and the visible rectangle corners) then you can loop through your objects to find which are inside using point in polygon detection.

Randolph Franklyn's for example.  Returns 1 for interior points and 0 for exterior points...

```
int pnpoly(int npol, float *xp, float *yp, float x, float y)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = npol-1; i < npol; j = i++) {
    if ((((yp[i] <= y) && (y < yp[j])) ||
         ((yp[j] <= y) && (y < yp[i]))) &&
        (x < (xp[j] - xp[i]) * (y - yp[i]) / (yp[j] - yp[i]) + xp[i]))
      c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the simplest way to do what you want(field of view) would be to first draw everything to screen, then draw black everywhere you don't want things to be seen.

So basically drawing darkness onto the no fog-of-war screen.

Comment: I don't want help with the drawing. This is so that I can find out **what needs to be hidden**.